# How to prevent function contructor arrays from being edited via get methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this code

```
function State(){
  const SecretState = {
    name: 'bob'
  }
  this.getState = () => SecretState;
  this.setState = (name) => SecretState.name = name;
}
const m = new State()

m.setState('Smith')

m.getState().name = 'Alice'

console.log(m.getState().name)
```

At the final console log, I should get "Smith". I want to prevent the ability to set the state within the `getState` method

Comment: `this.getState = () => ({...SecretState});`

Comment: What do you want to happen with `var o = m.getState(); o.name = "Alice"; console.log(o.name)`?

Comment: @trincot if we need to handle that usecase, we can try Getter and Setters. That way, changing object might not work. We can also make Object writable false, I guess

Comment: Sure, I know all that, but my question is for clarification from the asker.

Comment: As a side note ... hopefully the example is for demonstration purposes only since the to be set value, the return value and the naming of especially the setter are counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is, in JS objects are copied using reference. So getState is returning a reference instead of object.

Try updating to this instead:

```
this.getState = () => ({...SecretState});
```

What this does is it creates a new object and pass its reference. This way your `SecretState` is accessible only using setter. However, this will not work if you have deep nested objects as Object spread only works for first level

```js
function State(){
  const SecretState = {
    name: 'bob'
  }
  this.getState = () => ({...SecretState});
  this.setState = (name) => SecretState.name = name;
}
const m = new State()

m.setState('Smith')

m.getState().name = 'Alice'

console.log(m.getState().name)
```

Comment: By non-primitive, if you mean nested objects, like arrays or objects, that ius mentioned in answer already

Comment: Sorry, missed that  :p good job ... deep nested objects as long as SecretState is able to be JSON.stringify'd ... `this.getState = () => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(SecretState))`

Comment: stringify will remove all functions. So that is a bad idea. There is a thread on how to deep clone an object, refer it

Comment: the State in `SecretState` suggests an object that would not have functions :p

Comment: @Bravo ... one might consider [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) with a fallback to `stringify`/`parse`.